# Learning Google App Engine & BigTable

Tags: google-app-engine, bigtable

I have a traditional RDBMS based PHP app that I need to convert over to GAE and would like to properly learn how BigTable works prior to doing this.  However, I'd kinda like to do it through sample problems or examples that show the maximal way to think about and utilize a non RDBMS platform such as BigTable...

It seems that this would be the best route to take prior to just jumping in and screwing some things up in a one-to-one conversion that would likely happen by the both feet in first method.

Anyone able to recommend a good starting path that perhaps helped you or something of this nature that will properly initiate someone with App Engine and BigTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having a play with the App Engine Cookbook to see how things work. It has some really good examples and has helped me a lot when trying to understand the DataStore

http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/cat/?id=ahJhcHBlbmdpbmUtY29va2Jvb2tyFwsSCENhdGVnb3J5IglEYXRhc3RvcmUM

Answer (score 2):

A good way is to see the sources codes of a good projects running in GAE like [jaikuengine](http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/) and [rietveld](http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/).

For articles, [Google IO 2009 and 2010](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions.html#App%20Engine) and [GAE articles](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/) offer a good resource.

Also you can learn a Column-oriented Database in Wikipedia and see all other projects like cassandra...

Comment: Thanks for that last link.  Between the example code in the previous answer and your link to that article, it seems that I'll be moving in the right direction.